# $(window).load starts before initial ajax finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I encounter a weird problem here for which I can't find resolution on google.

On initial (first start) of my website `window.onload` from `canvas.js` (at the end of body) starts before my ajax request in `preload.js` (inside the ) finishes. But after a refresh everything works properly...

Why does it work after refresh but not on initial load? How do I make it work on the first start?

html structure:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Veto Designer</title>
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/preload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
.
.
.
<script src="js/canvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

preload.js

```js
//preloading some images
.
.
.
var urlFetch = "scripts/designhandler.php"
console.debug("starting ajax");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlFetch,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        sport: chosenSport
    },
    success: function(resp){
        mainData=resp;
        console.log(mainData);
    }
});
```

canvas.js:

```js
function doSomething(){
.
// this is what runs before the AJAX from preload.js
.
};
$(window).load(function(){
   doSomething();
});
```

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Probably works after a refresh because of caching

Comment: anyway of making it work on initial?

Comment: Do the ajax request on window load and then do something in the success of it? Or set async false like others are suggesting.

Comment: async false did the trick :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default mode for ajax-requests is asynchron, which means the request is sent at some random point. Javascript doesn`t wait for the request to finish and proceeds with the execution. To prevent this, you can use the setting

```
async:false,
```

Answer (score 4):

Your ajax call is asynchronous (the first A in AJAX) so window.load fires before that request finishes. Most likely it works on reload because the preloaded images are then cached.

Try running `doSomething()` inside the success callback, that should do the trick.

Comment: yes I considered it but it's not the best way in my case as there is a lot of images preloading from different sources so if we did this way, the function might be called before the window is loaded and most likely throw me tons of errors as the function requires everything to be loaded. Also I don't really want to put the actual ajax in window.load because the response data is used in different functions which are run on document.ready

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
async: false,
```

property in your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Could possibly be that you're loading jQuery from the Google API's website and not locally, which is causing a delay in jQuery being loaded.